# C# string marshalling and LocalAlloc

Tags: c#, c++, com, callback, marshalling

I have a COM callback from an unmanaged DLL that I need to use in C#.
The unmanaged DLL expects the callee to allocate memory using `LocalAlloc` (which the caller will `LocalFree`), populate it with `WSTR` and set `value` and `chars` to the WSTR pointer and string length respectively.

Code snippet I'm trying to convert to C#:

```
STDMETHODIMP CMyImpl::GetString(LPCSTR field, LPWSTR* value, int* chars) {
    CStringW ret;

    if (!strcmp(field, "matrix")) {
        ret = L"None";
        if (...)
            ret.Append(L"001");
        else if (...) 
            ret.Append(L"002");
        else
            ret.Append(L"003");
    }

    if (!ret.IsEmpty()) {
        int len = ret.GetLength();
        size_t sz = (len + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
        LPWSTR buf = (LPWSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sz);

        if (!buf) {
            return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }

        wcscpy_s(buf, len + 1, ret);
        *chars = len;
        *value = buf;

        return S_OK;
    }

    return E_INVALIDARG; 
}
```

What would the equivalent C# code be?

EDIT: COM Interface:

`[id(2)] HRESULT GetString([in] LPCSTR field, [out] LPWSTR* value, [out] int* chars);`

Comment: This doesn't look much like COM code.  The most important detail is the interface declaration, be sure to show us since it probably needs to be massaged.  The string hackery is simple enough with Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni().

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni()` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought HGLOBAL and HLOCAL were not compatible? The `GlobalAlloc` documentation explicitly says "It is not safe to free memory allocated with **GlobalAlloc** using **LocalFree**."

Comment: In spite of its name, the Marshal class does in fact use LocalAlloc/Free under the hood.

Comment: Strangely, `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni` uses LocalAlloc, not GlobalAlloc!

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward way would be to import [LocalAlloc](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.localalloc) function, convert the string to bytes using [UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and copy them to allocated memory with [Marshall.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146625%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: `FreeHGLobal` [is documented as using the Windows API `LocalFree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and so `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni` is necessarily using `LocalAlloc`, or something compatible with freeing via `LocalFree`, which is what matters here. This is probably both more efficient and simpler. At least with a comment about `FreeHGlobal` docs.