# How to copy the string text in c#?

Tags: c#

Hi,

When i copy the string text first time it copy successfully,When i copy the string text second time i am getting error, why i am getting error i don't know ,Any one help me to resolve this error, I am giving my code below.

```
        string text;
        OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero);
        if (id == 1)
        {
          text= "First time";
        }
        else if (id == 2)
        {
          text= "Second time";
        }


        var ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(text);
        SetClipboardData(13, ptr);
        CloseClipboard();
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13571530/869621 (see the last comment). Here is a possible explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24698804/869621

Comment: Thank you for reply all, I am getting this error :  An unhandled win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe [6612].